# how to create dynamic class using c# in asp.net

Tags: c#, dynamic

Is it possible to do the following in C# ?  I am fetching data from a database. At run time I can compute the number of columns and data types of the columns fetched. Next I want to "generate" a class with these data types as fields. I also want to store all the records that I fetched in a collection. The problem is that I want to do both step 1 and 2 at runtime  Is this possible? I am using C# currently but I can shift to something else if i need to.

Comment: Does it need to be a runtime compiled class or do you just want a container for your data? Would maybe a DataTable be sufficient? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: no because i am using a dropdownlist in asp page and i am calling a method in buisness access layer which gets the data from data access layer where the return type of the method is list<T>

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Take a look at [`System.Reflection.Emit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit(v=vs.110).aspx) namespace. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_8) are the working examples of dynamic type creation. The code at the end of this answer is taken from the last link.

However, it is a very small set of issues, that can be solved by dynamic creation of class. It is very slow and for your task it is a great example of bad smell code.

If you are working with relational database, I guess, you are already know the required properties for classes, so declare it yourself or work with `DataTable` - it is a good practice.

If you are working with non-relational database, and/or does not want to declare classes it is better to work with `Dictionary<string, object>` or `Hashtable` instead of dynamic class.

If previous solutions does not fit, take a look at [anonymous types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types). It is kindly better than dynamic creation of classes.

If you does not trust any of previous solutions, the worst way is to use `dynamic` keyword or [`ExpandoObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx) and setting propeties manually, and it is still better.

Dynamic declaration of class it is hardcore for that, who want to create dynamic assemblies and generate code on IL. It is really hardcore. If I did not change your mind, so below is the code for class creation (copypasted from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_8)).

```
/*
public class MyDynamicType
{
    private int m_number;

    public MyDynamicType() : this(42) {}
    public MyDynamicType(int initNumber)
    {
        m_number = initNumber;
    }

    public int Number
    {
        get { return m_number; }
        set { m_number = value; }
    }

    public int MyMethod(int multiplier)
    {
        return m_number * multiplier;
    }
}
*/

AssemblyName aName = new AssemblyName("DynamicAssemblyExample");
AssemblyBuilder ab = 
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(
        aName, 
        AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);

// For a single-module assembly, the module name is usually
// the assembly name plus an extension.
ModuleBuilder mb = 
    ab.DefineDynamicModule(aName.Name, aName.Name + ".dll");

TypeBuilder tb = mb.DefineType(
    "MyDynamicType", 
     TypeAttributes.Public);

// Add a private field of type int (Int32).
FieldBuilder fbNumber = tb.DefineField(
    "m_number", 
    typeof(int), 
    FieldAttributes.Private);

// Define a constructor that takes an integer argument and 
// stores it in the private field. 
Type[] parameterTypes = { typeof(int) };
ConstructorBuilder ctor1 = tb.DefineConstructor(
    MethodAttributes.Public, 
    CallingConventions.Standard, 
    parameterTypes);

ILGenerator ctor1IL = ctor1.GetILGenerator();
// For a constructor, argument zero is a reference to the new
// instance. Push it on the stack before calling the base
// class constructor. Specify the default constructor of the 
// base class (System.Object) by passing an empty array of 
// types (Type.EmptyTypes) to GetConstructor.
ctor1IL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
ctor1IL.Emit(OpCodes.Call, 
    typeof(object).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes));
// Push the instance on the stack before pushing the argument
// that is to be assigned to the private field m_number.
ctor1IL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
ctor1IL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
ctor1IL.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fbNumber);
ctor1IL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

// Define a default constructor that supplies a default value
// for the private field. For parameter types, pass the empty
// array of types or pass null.
ConstructorBuilder ctor0 = tb.DefineConstructor(
    MethodAttributes.Public, 
    CallingConventions.Standard, 
    Type.EmptyTypes);

ILGenerator ctor0IL = ctor0.GetILGenerator();
// For a constructor, argument zero is a reference to the new
// instance. Push it on the stack before pushing the default
// value on the stack, then call constructor ctor1.
ctor0IL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
ctor0IL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_S, 42);
ctor0IL.Emit(OpCodes.Call, ctor1);
ctor0IL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

// Define a property named Number that gets and sets the private 
// field.
//
// The last argument of DefineProperty is null, because the
// property has no parameters. (If you don't specify null, you must
// specify an array of Type objects. For a parameterless property,
// use the built-in array with no elements: Type.EmptyTypes)
PropertyBuilder pbNumber = tb.DefineProperty(
    "Number", 
    PropertyAttributes.HasDefault, 
    typeof(int), 
    null);

// The property "set" and property "get" methods require a special
// set of attributes.
MethodAttributes getSetAttr = MethodAttributes.Public | 
    MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.HideBySig;

// Define the "get" accessor method for Number. The method returns
// an integer and has no arguments. (Note that null could be 
// used instead of Types.EmptyTypes)
MethodBuilder mbNumberGetAccessor = tb.DefineMethod(
    "get_Number", 
    getSetAttr, 
    typeof(int), 
    Type.EmptyTypes);

ILGenerator numberGetIL = mbNumberGetAccessor.GetILGenerator();
// For an instance property, argument zero is the instance. Load the 
// instance, then load the private field and return, leaving the
// field value on the stack.
numberGetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
numberGetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fbNumber);
numberGetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

// Define the "set" accessor method for Number, which has no return
// type and takes one argument of type int (Int32).
MethodBuilder mbNumberSetAccessor = tb.DefineMethod(
    "set_Number", 
    getSetAttr, 
    null, 
    new Type[] { typeof(int) });

ILGenerator numberSetIL = mbNumberSetAccessor.GetILGenerator();
// Load the instance and then the numeric argument, then store the
// argument in the field.
numberSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
numberSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
numberSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fbNumber);
numberSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

// Last, map the "get" and "set" accessor methods to the 
// PropertyBuilder. The property is now complete. 
pbNumber.SetGetMethod(mbNumberGetAccessor);
pbNumber.SetSetMethod(mbNumberSetAccessor);

// Define a method that accepts an integer argument and returns
// the product of that integer and the private field m_number. This
// time, the array of parameter types is created on the fly.
MethodBuilder meth = tb.DefineMethod(
    "MyMethod", 
    MethodAttributes.Public, 
    typeof(int), 
    new Type[] { typeof(int) });

ILGenerator methIL = meth.GetILGenerator();
// To retrieve the private instance field, load the instance it
// belongs to (argument zero). After loading the field, load the 
// argument one and then multiply. Return from the method with 
// the return value (the product of the two numbers) on the 
// execution stack.
methIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
methIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fbNumber);
methIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
methIL.Emit(OpCodes.Mul);
methIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

// Finish the type.
Type t = tb.CreateType();
```

Comment: If the great amount of developers will use this instead of precompiled classes, I will be very demanded developer :)

Comment: Thanks for response, but it is not working to  me,could you please explain steps how to i approach to get the dynamic class with  the above code

Comment: @lavangoud check the last line `Type t = tb.CreateType();` after this line declaration of your dynamic class will be stored in variable `t`. If you want to create instance of this class you can use `Activator.CreateInstance(t)`. It is an actual dynamic class, generated at runtime. Or you want to get complete `*.cs` file?